# my discord bot only reacts on direct messages but not on my server's channel

Tags: python, discord, bots

I made a discord bot based on Python. However, it only responds through direct message, and it does not respond on the channel.
I also gave the bot permission to write messages and write threads on the channel, but it doesn't respond. I'd appreciate your help.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run('MTA4NjYxOTU0MjQ4NDE2MDUxMg.GXvBd2.DadwkNpAfbUUpV-XW2cG3ERHvPAn3z3o3L8XAk')
```

I asked because the bot I made didn't work as I programmed. I've tried several permission modifications, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're missing the `message_content` intent. As per the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content), (and Discord's documentation), without that privileged Intent enabled then the bot can only retrieve message content for direct messages or messages the bot is mentioned in. [Intent.message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content).

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

The above enables `message_content` intent in the code; make sure to head to the Discord Developer Portal to enable the intent for your bot as well. [Primer on intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#need-message-content-intent).